# Filter data in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JSON array where it contains an objects having name and rating fields. I want to filter that array where rating is 5. It might be an easy one find but I got stuck.

Below is my json object.

```
let products = [
{
  "name" : "product 1",
  "rating" : 5   
},
{
  "name" : "product 2",
  "rating" : 4
},
{
  "name" : "product 3",
  "rating" : 5
},
{
  "name" : "product 4",
  "rating" : 2
}]
```

Here I am using filter functionality but unable to understand how to use it properly.

This is the function I have written but it's not working.

```
const prod = (products) => {

    products.filter((proct) => {
        if(proct === 5){
          console.log(proct.name);
        }
    });
}

prod(products);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` function must return a boolean as result

> Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return a value that coerces to true to keep the element, or to false otherwise.

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let products = [{ "name": "product 1", "rating": 5 }, { "name": "product 2", "rating": 4 }, { "name": "product 3", "rating": 5 }, { "name": "product 4", "rating": 2 } ]

products = products.filter(({rating}) => rating === 5)

console.log(products)
```

Each item in your array is an object, and I guess you are looking for **rating===5**.

Your function should be:

```js
let products = [{ "name": "product 1", "rating": 5 }, { "name": "product 2", "rating": 4 }, { "name": "product 3", "rating": 5 }, { "name": "product 4", "rating": 2 } ]

const prod = (products) => {
  products.filter((proct) => {
    if (proct.rating === 5) {
      console.log(proct.name);
      return true;
    }
    return false
  });
}

prod(products)
```

---

Getting just `name` key:

Take a look at [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function which create a new array from old array:

```
.map(({name}) => name)
```

Full code:

```js
let products = [{ "name": "product 1", "rating": 5 }, { "name": "product 2", "rating": 4 }, { "name": "product 3", "rating": 5 }, { "name": "product 4", "rating": 2 } ]

products = products.filter(({rating}) => rating === 5).map(({name}) => name)

console.log(products)
```

Comment: how can I get the output along with the key like `{name: product 1}`.

Comment: The answer updated. @Digvijay

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not checking the property. But the object itself. Use the `.` operator to check the specific property:

```js
let products = [
{
  "name" : "product 1",
  "rating" : 5   
},
{
  "name" : "product 2",
  "rating" : 4
},
{
  "name" : "product 3",
  "rating" : 5
},
{
  "name" : "product 4",
  "rating" : 2
}]

const prod = (products) => {

    products.filter((proct) => {
        if(proct.rating === 5){
          console.log(proct.name);
        }
    });
}

prod(products);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is comparing `proct`, an object, to the value `5`. You probably forgot to access the `rating` property of `proct`:

```
products.filter((proct) => {
    if(proct.rating === 5){
      console.log(proct.name);
    }
});
```

However, you are using `filter` wrong. Filter is a method whose entire point is to get all the elements in the array that answer a condition and return them, and not just iterate over an array and execute code (that's what `forEach` is for). A more correct code would be:

```
const filteredProducts = products.filter((proct) => proct.rating === 5);
console.log(filteredProducts); // [{ name: "product 1", rating: 5 }, { name: "product 3", rating: 5 }]

filteredProducts.forEach((proct) => console.log(proct.name));
```

This solution first retrieves all the products whose rating is 5 and then iterates over each of them to print their name.